# Can the construct of "addiction" induce addiction or at least make it worse?

Tags: construct-validity

So, I have been wondering today. Can humanly created constructs like 'addiction' make matters worse for someone who might have not thought he was an addict before?

To explain a little further, when I got together with my partner, it has been a completely new experience, in a very positive way. 
Sex was a new thing for me which I anticipated would be something beautiful and uniting and so I was looking forward to it. But when things got serious, something did not work as expected and that can really scare someone experiencing it for the first time. I would have never expected to face erectile dysfunction ever, but that was because I just did not know about it in the way I do now.

I have overcome that and learned many valuable things from it, but it took time until I realized it was of psychological cause and had absolutely nothing to do with my body. In retrospect I wonder if my way would have been different, maybe even quicker, if I just had not known about things like porn addiction.

I am saying that because the first thing I found was NoFap which is very closely related to porn addiction. And as I started reading into that topic more and more, I just assumed NoFap was the holy grail and would get me back on track in a matter of weeks. One thing that scared me from the beginning though was the huge amount of people that wrote about huge cravings and libido coming to a full stop and even disappearing completely.

I never faced such problems and all in all I had absolutely no problem not watching porn. I was just assuming I might be one of the few guys that has huge willpower when it comes to things concerning addiction or similar.

Turns out, I probably never was addicted to porn, which is a good thing. But what left me wondering as of today is the question, if the pure existence of a construct like addiction makes matters worse... Obviously, there is a huge difference between telling someone he does to much of something and saying that it is bad for him against telling someone he is just straight up addicted.

But knowing that you are a self proclaimed addict and somewhat making it your reality makes things worse because you get into a spiral of self doubt compared to just having to turn down consumption of your addiction vehicle. I will obviously be left with the question if just not knowing about porn addiction would have made my 'curing process' quicker, but I still think it is an interesting question nevertheless.

Fairly long question and I hope I made my point clear, but does the construct of addiction make the problem itself worse for someone affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the issue here is not philosophical, but psychological.

(I use alcohol rather than sex a as my example, because a lot of people already distrust the notion of sex addiction.  So this speaks to a more general audience.)

What causes these problems is not the idea of addiction, but the oversimplification and overemphasis that it has undergone in our society as an explanation for all kinds of other behaviors.

We like to blame drugs or other external influences for our behavior.  But we are often just using drugs to pretend, to fail to internalize our obligations and thereby to escape consequences.  Many drugs do not actually change your ability to make reasonable decisions very much.  But they make it easier to explain your failure away.

That is a purposeful lie, based on an incorrect understanding we cultivate socially for just this reason.  The idea of addiction does not create the wish to delude oneself.  Without it these folks would still find a way.  They might blame the Devil, or develop a different psychological symptom, or hand their decisions over to a proxy, or undergo some ritual of forgiveness, or just lose track of the facts 'accidentally on purpose'.  Every society has these devices, even ones that take a very hard line against drugs.  We just add drugs as another one.

To me the real complexity of addiction is illustrated by the overall prevalence of two myths:

First of all: Excess and addiction are only vaguely linked.  One can be addicted to alcohol even if one never drinks to excess, and actually consumes much less alcohol than an ordinary non-addict.  Addiction means there are strong physiological or psychological reactions to the absence of the substance.  And if one drinks sparingly but constantly for years, so that there is always a given level of alcohol in one's system, but a very low one, one can have those withdrawal symptoms late in life.

Second: Excess is usually a different psychological symptom, not primarily related to addiction.  Psychodynamically we often see alcohol as something else: a marker for displacement, a means of escape, access to an alter ego, a narcissistic self-object...  That causes usage, which may ultimately lead to addiction.  But if one is using alcohol excessively for some reason, it does not automatically make you addicted.

You might find a different crutch and move on, leaving your previous dependency behind.  We see this happen in reality a lot, and from a given psychological point of view, some of these are among the several ways that AA can work -- by creating a secondary self-object as the "Higher Power", by creating a social network where one can be a different (more honest) version of oneself and use that as an alter ego, etc.  In those cases, what AA (or NoFap, etc.) is 'treating' is not any addiction, it is just human nature.